# Why, for all $i$, $Z(G)\neq \bar x_i$

Tags: group-theory

In my class today my teacher wrote the following:

> Let $G$ be a group and let $\bar x$ denote the conjugacy class of $x \in G$. If $G$ is finite, then there is a finite number of such classes with more than one element: $\bar x_1, \bar x_2,...,\bar x_k$. Then we have:
> $$G=Z(G)\cup \bar x_1\cup \bar x_2 \cup ... \cup \bar x_k$$
> All these sets are pairwise disjoint

I understand why if $x_i\neq x_j$ then $\bar x_i \neq \bar x_j$, but I con't figure out why for any $i$, $Z(G)\neq \bar x_i$ would be true. Why is this the case?

Thanks.

Comment: It's related to the [class equation](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Class_equation_of_a_group).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $x$ is any element of $G$, then the conjugacy class $\overline{x} = \{ gxg^{-1} : g\in G\}$ is the singleton set $\{x\}$ if and only if $x$ lies in the center of $G$.  By definition, the elements $x_1, ... , x_k$ in your post should be chosen to not lie in the center of $G$.  They are representatives of the conjugacy classes which are not singleton sets.

Thus $Z(G)$ is the disjoint union of the conjugacy classes which each consist of only one element, and $\overline{x_1}, ... , \overline{x_k}$ are the remaining conjugacy classes, each of which contains more than one element.